# Reveal.js slides generating 404 on GitHub Pages

Tags: r, github-pages, blogdown

I'm very confused as it used to work just fine.

I have a `blogdown` website hosted on GitHub Pages, that includes reveal.js slides.
I presented those slides in the summary of 2019 from that website.

The pages where slides should be are now generating a 404 error when browsing the website on GitHub Pages (e.g., https://kevinrue.github.io/slides/bioc2019-flashtalk/#/), while the site served locally by `blogdown::serve_site()` shows those slides without problem at the corresponding local URL.

For instance the 404 error above should display the slides in this file
https://github.com/kevinrue/kevinrue.github.io/blob/master/slides/bioc2019-flashtalk/index.html

I'm really stuck after trying a number of things. I'm happy to take suggestions and report here on their success.

Any suggestion is welcome!

Kind regards
Kevin

---

PS1:

Somehow, netlify shows those pages just fine: https://quirky-jepsen-c23a11.netlify.app/slides/bioc2019-flashtalk/#/

I've also contacted GitHub Support in case it could be anything on their side.

Comment: It seems you have resolved the issue? If so, it might be good if you could explain how you made it, in case other people have similar problems in the future.

Comment: Thank @YihuiXie for reminding me. I posted the answer now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem solved by the GitHub support team.
The issue was due to a new repository called "slides" on my account, which also deployed files to GitHub and interfered/overrode the "slides" subfolder of my github.io website.

Basically: make sure you avoid name conflicts between subdirectories of your main github website and repository names.